# Stop proceed to next controller if the username and password is wrong SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, parsing, ios8, xcode6

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
    {
        if (identifier == "gotoLogin")
        {
            if txtUsername.text.isEmpty || txtPassword.text.isEmpty
            {
                let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "Cannot blank", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alertView.show()
                return false
            }
            else if txtUsername.text != "" && txtPassword.text != ""
            {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(txtUsername.text, password: txtPassword.text, block: { (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if(error == nil)
                    {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoLogin", sender: self)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        var errorCode = error?.code
                        switch errorCode!
                        {
                        case 101:
                            var alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Incorrect Username or Password", message: "Try Again!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                            alertView.show()
                            break
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                    }
                })
                return true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

[image: This picture is showing it proceeds to next controller even with the wrong username and password, and the alertview is pop out in next controller instead of in the login page.]

I've made a validation if the username and password are incorrect. So if both of them are incorrect, it should be stay in the login page to show the alertview. However, in this case, it proceeds to next controller then only show the alertview. How to stay at the login page even the username and password are incorrect instead of proceed to the next controller.

Comment: I think you should try to do it the other way around, don’t do anything UNLESS they entered the correct credentials

Comment: @milo526 as a good application, we need to inform user when they are entered incorrectly what...

Comment: Your question states that you want to stop the proceeding  to the next view controller. Instead don’t proceed, first check if there is an error. Display the error if there is one, if there is no error THEN go to the next view controller.

Comment: @milo526 ya, I've did that validation, but the validation just weird, it pop out the alertview in the next controller, but not pop out at the login page there

Answer (score 0):

Milo is correct, the best way of handling this situation is not to fire the segue until the user has entered correct details.

Check the form on submission, handle the success by triggering the segue, handler the failure by throwing an alert.

Arrange your code like so:

```
 func onSubmitButton(sender: AnyObject){
     if username !="" && password !="" {
         success = checkusername(username,password)
         //if this is an http request you probably want to do a delegate pattern 
         //and create a callback instead- just create 2 delegate functions-
        // one for success and one for fail and pass self of vc to http request)
         if success{
              performSegue();
         }else{
              clearForm();
              throwAlert()
         }
    }
```

Something like that is the pattern you are after.

Comment: base on this code, do you mind help me to take a look on how to stop at the page when both username and password are incorrect and pop out the alertview.